# Searching subelement array values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

My JSON is formatted a little weirdly because it's converted from XML, but here's the basic structure:

```
{
  "World": {
    "Continents": {
      "Continent": [
        "Asia",
        "Europe",
        "Africa"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to return cases where Continent = Asia. I've tried quite a few things but this is the one I suspected would work:

```
db.testing.find( { "World.Continents": { $elemMatch: { "Continent": "Asia" }}})
```

I've also butchered various queries based on a find on World.Continents.Continent but it's thrown back myriad errors at me for various syntax reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
db.testing.find( { "World.Continents.Continent":  "Africa" } )
```

Comment: Wow. Yeah. I don't know whether that was so straight-forward that I didn't bother to try it or whether I fat-fingered it. Thanks for the help.